# SPWeb.AlternateCSSUrl equivalent Client Side Object Model

Tags: client-object-model, css, csom

Does someone know the equivalent of SPWeb.AlternateCssUrl in the client side object model?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any, Check this MSDN link out for more information,

Here it exists
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb_properties.aspx

Client Web it doesn't exists
http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web_properties.aspx

JS.Web property doesn't exits
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244873.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The property is exposed in the V16 Client DLLS for SharePoint online

Answer (score 0):

According to [UserVoice driving improvements to SharePoint API](http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/uservoice-driving-improvements-sharepoint-api/) Microsoft released [SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online solution packs](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42030) that contains the following  change to the existing API:

> `Web` object exposes `AlternateCssUrl` property via CSOM (.Net, REST, JS)

Alternatively you could install the latest versions of [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585) or [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Example:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    ctx.Web.AlternateCssUrl = "/SiteAssets/Contoso.css";
    ctx.Web.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```